# IS ingestion data (in batch)from google storage to bigquery, using dataflow pipeline(custom not built in) FREE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

is ingestion data (in batch)from google storage to bigquery, using dataflow (beam, python) to perform some transformations on these data then load them on bigquery is FREE or it considered as API and they apply api cost?

Answer (score 0):

**It is NOT free.**

According to [Apache Beam's Documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-bigquery) :

> BigQueryIO write transforms use APIs that are subject to BigQuery’s Quota and Pricing policies.

The pricing for [BigQuery Data ingestion](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data_ingestion_pricing) using `BigQuery Storage Write API` will be `$0.025 per 1 GB`